# Как запретить создание файла .recently-used в Linux?

Tags: linux

Как запретить создание файла .recently-used в Linux ?

Графическая оболочка - Mate.

Comment: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/desktop/13060044

Comment: http://debuntu.ru/note/kak-otklyuchit-v-ubuntu-nedavnie-dokumenty

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/262568/how-do-i-permanently-stop-ubuntu-from-recording-and-displaying-recently-used-f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы очистить "последние файлы" Nautilus (И не только Nautilus) нужно удалить этот файл командой:

```
rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

Чтобы отключить функцию recently-used:

```
gedit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini # вместо gedit может быть любой текстовик
```

и под "[Settings]", вставляем следующие строчки:

```
gtk-recent-files-max-age=0
gtk-recent-files-limit=0
```

В итоге файл settings.ini должен выглядеть так:

```
[Settings]
gtk-recent-files-max-age=0
gtk-recent-files-limit=0
```

[Источник](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262568/how-do-i-permanently-stop-ubuntu-from-recording-and-displaying-recently-used-f)